# Inconsistent height of Card widget in Flutter with ListTile as child

Tags: flutter, height, tile

When I am using Card and ListTile as its child, the height of cards differs based on the number of text lines of the subtitle parameter of ListTile. If title and subtitle are single lines of text there's some sort of top and bottom padding (highlighted with green rectangles). However, if subtitle consists of several lines of text, there's no top and bottom padding and the height of the card is smaller.
What causes this inconsistency? How can I remove this padding from cards 1 and 2 or add it to card 3?

```
class CardList extends StatelessWidget {
  List<List<String>> cardList = [
    ["Apple", "Fruit"],
    ["Book", "Thing"],
    [
      "Lorem ipsum",
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate tortor non mi gravida, nec"
    ]
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: cardList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
          return Card(
              elevation: 2.0,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(cardList[position][0]),
                subtitle: Text(cardList[position][1]),
              ));
        });
  }
}
```

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju0nj.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `ListTile` works out of the box, you could check the source code if you want, but don't worry, this is Flutter, you can create and customize your own widget very easily.

```
class MyListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;

  const MyListTile({Key key, this.title, this.subtitle}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: textTheme.subhead,
          ),
          subtitle != null
              ? Text(
                  subtitle,
                  style: textTheme.body1,
                )
              : const SizedBox.shrink()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: cardList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
          return Card(
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: MyListTile(
              title: cardList[position][0],
              subtitle: cardList[position][1],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is an approach I would definetely consider in future. I also found where tile height is configured (list_tile.dart -> double get _defaultTileHeight {}). It returns one tile height if subtitle consists of one line and another if subtitle consists of two or more lines.

Comment: Update: I was wrong. It doesn't take into account how many lines a subtitle has. It takes into account parameter "isThreeLine" (which is false by default) and if there is a subtitle at all. If you need to get rid of padding in card 1 and card 2 from my example, you can simply set 56 instead of 72 here: if (isTwoLine) return isDense ? 64.0 : 72.0; Then if you need to add padding to three all cards, you can do it by specifiying "contentPadding" parameter when creating ListTile.